# Maximum update depth exceeded in useFocusEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-query

I'm running `useFocusEffect` to make an API call(with reactQuery), but I'm having this error:

`Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

This is the specific code that throwns the error, I'm don't know if error comes from reactQuery [useMutation](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/mutations) or from [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/) from react navigation:

````js
export const OrderStatementLoading = () => {
  const {  
    mutateAsync: createSchedulePayment,
    isLoading: isLoadingSave,
    isSuccess: isSuccessSave,
    reset,
  } = useMutation(//...useMutationParams);

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      createSchedulePayment()
        .then(() => console.log('success'))
        .catch(() => console.log('error'))
        .finally(() => {
          reset();
        });
    }, [reset, createSchedulePayment]),
  );

  return {// redered content}
};```
````

Answer (score 1):

The functions returned from `useMutation` are referentially stable, so you can put them in dependency arrays of `useEffect`.

I have quickly tried this in a codesandbox, and this works fine:

```
  const { mutateAsync, reset } = useMutation(() => Promise.resolve(5));
  React.useEffect(() => {
    mutateAsync()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("success");
      })
      .then(() => reset());
  }, [mutateAsync, reset]);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/usemutation-effect-4f3r6

So I think it must have something todo with how `useFocusEffect` works together with `useCallback` ?

The docs you linked to say:

> The useFocusEffect is analogous to React's useEffect hook. The only difference is that it only runs if the screen is currently focused.

If that is true, I'm wondering why the `useCallback` is needed instead of passing dependencies directly to `useFocusEffect`... It is explicitly mentioned though:

> Note: To avoid the running the effect too often, it's important to wrap the callback in useCallback before passing it to useFocusEffect as shown in the example.

And the source also specifies the function you pass [as a dependency to useEffect](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/b91c9b05ff96727f5fa6ef0bec51b5d7eac06600/packages/core/src/useFocusEffect.tsx#L111), so it seems that useCallback is indeed necessary.